# Checkboxes for has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails and I am trying to create an app where users can belong to many teams and teams contain many users. Here are my model classes and the migration pages. I am trying to make a signup page where you can click on different teams to assign the user. Having a default none team would be good to implement.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_many :teams 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
end


class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  attr_accessible :name
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.references :teams
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :users
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the code in my controller for the creation method

```
  def create
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash.keep[:success] =  @user.name + " Added to list of Users!"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render 'index'
    end
  end
```

Here is the code in my view file

```
<% for team in @teams %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'user[team]', team.name, @user.team_name.include?(team.name)%> 
  <%=  team.name -%>
<% end %>
```

However the output is just "Team". I am not sure if the value is actually getting passed onto the object.

edit: I just needed to read the checkbox doc sheet. The parameter that was causing the trouble could just have been turned into true and false for the initlized value.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because here is no `team_name method for the user object? Did you mean perhaps?

```
@user.teams.map(&:name).include?(team.name)
```

Or even better

```
@user.teams.include?(team)
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. what I used was @user.teams.include?(team.name)

Comment: But I get a new error called `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: team` Do you know why this is?

Comment: Have you tried using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your `Team` model? Try declaring `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users` in your `Team` model. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment for details.

Comment: I tried the accepts nested attruibutes but i get the same error

Comment: I think you have a typo.  In your `User` model, you should be declaring to accept nested attributes for `:teams` like this - `accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams`. If your view/controller is saving from the perspective of the `Team` model, then it should declare it for `:users`.

Comment: @theSshow I fixed that type but I am getting the same error. I am not sure why

Comment: The problem was that The id and the name were being funky. I changed both of them into team.name: `<%= check_box_tag team.name, team.name, @user.teams.map(&:name).include?(team.name)%>`